Google Sheets Get Value From Another Sheet Where Value Equals
I'm using Google Sheets with two sheets:
- Quests (Sheet 1)
  -- id
  -- quest_name
- Tasks (Sheet 2)
  -- quest_id

I'd like to output a value using a formula where the value of quest_id on the Tasks sheet matches the value of id on the Quests sheet.
So I'd like to use the Quest ID value in Tasks and match that to the ID column in the Quests sheet, and then output the quest_name from Quests in a cell in Tasks.
How can I accomplish this? Thank you

showing a couple of tables might help to see how you have your data, but roughly what you want is this:
=VLOOKUP(cell_with_id_in_task_sheet,Quests!A:B,2,0)
This assuming id is column A and quest name is column B
